# Updating via cursor is taking a lot of time

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I'm performing address association by taking the addr_id and updating it in two tables (same table and another table) for different columns. However it is taking huge time even though I use parallel hint with degree of paralleism as 500. Could you assist here ? Below is the procedure.

```
PROCEDURE 
ADD_ASOC AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(500) */ ADDR_ID FROM TEMP_ADDR WHERE BATCH_RANGE BETWEEN 100 AND 900;

TYPE CURSOR_ATT IS TABLE OF C1%ROWTYPE;

L_CURSOR CURSOR_ATT;

    BEGIN
    OPEN C1;
    LOOP

    FETCH C1 BULK COLLECT INTO          L_CURSOR LIMIT 5000;
EXIT WHEN L_CURSOR.COUNT = 0;

FOR I IN 1 .. L_CURSOR.COUNT LOOP

UPDATE  /*+ PARALLEL(500) */ MAIN_ADDR SET ADR_NAME = L_CURSOR(I).ADDR_ID||'RESIDENCE'
WHERE ADDR_ID = L_CURSOR(I).ADDR_ID;



UPDATE  /*+ PARALLEL(500) */ TEMP_ADDR SET ADR_NAME = L_CURSOR(I).ADDR_ID||'RESIDENCE'

WHERE ADDR_ID = L_CURSOR(I).ADDR_ID
AND BATCH_RANGE BETWEEN 100 AND 900;

COMMIT;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
CLOSE C1;
END;
COMMIT;
```

I executed using degree of paralleism as 500 but in vain.

Comment: Parallelism isn't used on single row operations. Your  hint on those updates would be ignored which is a good thing because 500 would swamp just about any database system out there. Don't just throw big numbers at things, that can cause a lot of damage.  As to your issue, a single update or merge statement to handle all the rows is far better than PL/SQL program. And if you did want to do this row by row for some reason, you would need to ensure ADDR_ID is indexed.

Comment: Use `forall` statement that is many times faster that `for` loop update. See example in [PL/SQL docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-6D4A1425-64DD-4723-8AAE-87B0A51A2854__BABEDFJE). But it worth nothing to complicate the code without any extra PL/SQL processing between fetch and update: do `merge` statement instead of sepect-fetch-update, possibly with `dbms_parallel_execute` to split input data into batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A `parallel` hint on a single-row `update` statement is, at best, pointless.
- `commit` is very expensive.  A `commit` on every single iteration of a loop would be catastrophically slow.
- Doing a `forall` is more efficient than a `for` loop.  Doing the update in a single SQL statement would be the most efficient approach.
- How did you come up with 500 as the degrees of parallelism for your `select` statement?  It seems highly, highly unlikely that is a reasonable number.

Beyond that, what have you done to trace your code or to see what's taking time.  We can certainly guess at things that might be slow but we have no way to see if, for example, one of your tables is missing an index on `addr_id` or if there are a bunch of unindexed foreign keys that need to be managed or if there are triggers that are slowing things down.

The `forall` approach that would be faster (not as fast as individual `update` statements but better than row-by-row processing in a loop).

```
FORALL I IN 1 .. L_CURSOR.COUNT
  UPDATE MAIN_ADDR 
     SET ADR_NAME = L_CURSOR(I).ADDR_ID||'RESIDENCE'
   WHERE ADDR_ID = L_CURSOR(I).ADDR_ID;

FORALL I IN 1 .. L_CURSOR.COUNT
  UPDATE TEMP_ADDR 
     SET ADR_NAME = L_CURSOR(I).ADDR_ID||'RESIDENCE'
   WHERE ADDR_ID = L_CURSOR(I).ADDR_ID
     AND BATCH_RANGE BETWEEN 100 AND 900;
```

UPDATE  /*+ PARALLEL(500) */ TEMP_ADDR SET ADR_NAME = L_CURSOR(I).ADDR_ID||'RESIDENCE'

WHERE ADDR_ID = L_CURSOR(I).ADDR_ID
AND BATCH_RANGE BETWEEN 100 AND 900;

Comment: I'm trying to update more than 150K records that are present in the TEMP_ADDR table. Also, could you demonstrate how to do FOR ALL instead of FOR in my above procedure. And how do I do a single update as I've to update two tables and not one table. Finally, if parallel hint is pointless, is there any other hint I can use to make the procedure execute faster ?

Comment: @Cool_Oracle - I mean a single `update` per table.  The fastest approach would be two `update` statements, no cursor, no loop, no `forall`.  My guess is that simply removing the `commit` probably makes your code "fast enough" assuming Oracle rightly ignores all your parallelism hints.  But, again, it's helpful if you can include some sort of tracing/ profiling/ AWR/ ASH information in your post so we're not guessing about what might be causing slowness.

Answer (score 3):

You do not appear to need cursors or loops and can use a `MERGE` statement and an `UPDATE` statement

```sql
PROCEDURE ADD_ASOC
AS
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO MAIN_ADDR m
  USING TEMP_ADDR t
  ON ( m.addr_id = t.addr_id AND t.BATCH_RANGE BETWEEN 100 AND 900)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN;
    UPDATE
    SET ADR_NAME = t.ADDR_ID||'RESIDENCE';


  UPDATE TEMP_ADDR
  SET ADR_NAME = ADDR_ID||'RESIDENCE'
  WHERE BATCH_RANGE BETWEEN 100 AND 900;
END;
```

*Note: If you `COMMIT` in a procedure then you cannot use multiple procedures and then if the last one fails choose to `ROLLBACK` them all. Instead you should remove the `COMMIT` from the procedures and call `COMMIT` from the session where you invoke the procedure then you will be able to chain multiple procedures together. (Plus, repeatedly using `COMMIT` is very slow.)*

Comment: When I use merge, I am getting an error stating that unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables. This is expected as the query in the using clause returns more than 1 row. This is expected as we can have multiple T.ADDR_ID values. So, is there a work-around for this?